# EMR stuck at bootstrap script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, facebook-prophet, pystan

Am trying to run a bootstrap file at EMR to installed `facebook prophet` which seems to have an issue requiring to install `dev-tools`, `the bootstrap.sh` simply runs

**bootstrap.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
sudo yum install python3-devel python3-libs python3-tools
#sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/requirements.txt .
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade -r ./requirements.txt
```

,output logs shows the below
[image]

and errors logs shows

[image]

but then the cluster is stuck for 1 hour before failing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add `-y` flag to `yum` inorder to pypass any user prompting